# MediaPlayer does not play song,Give error java.net.URISyntaxException: Illegal character in path

Tags: android

I would like Playing online song in my application, So i have used mediaplayer for playing song.
Then it give Urisyntax error,I have confused about these error.
My code is,

```
package com.yeshuduniya;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URISyntaxException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import com.Model.GallryModel;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.media.AudioManager;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.media.MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener;
import android.media.MediaPlayer.OnErrorListener;
import android.media.MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.os.PowerManager;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.view.Window;
import android.view.WindowManager;
import android.view.animation.Animation;
import android.view.animation.TranslateAnimation;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.SeekBar;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.os.PowerManager.WakeLock;

public class Songs_Player extends Activity implements OnClickListener ,OnCompletionListener
{
    Uri uri;
    URL url;
    private MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = null;
    private boolean      isPlaying = false;
    private String song_url;
    Handler seekHandler = new Handler();
    TextView txt_song_name;
    private static int classID = 579; // just a number
    SeekBar seek_bar;
    WakeLock wakeLock;
    ProgressDialog progressDialogue;

    private static final String[] EXTENSIONS = { ".mp3", ".mid", ".wav", ".ogg", ".mp4" }; //Playable Extensions
    List<String> trackArtworks; //Track artwork names
    ImageView bg; //Track artwork
    Button btn_Play,btn_prev,btn_next; //The play button will need to change from 'play' to 'pause', so we need an instance of it
    int currentTrack; //index of current track selected
    int type; //0 for loading from assets, 1 for loading from SD card
    ArrayList<GallryModel> songList;

    @SuppressWarnings({ "unchecked", "deprecation" })
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_songs__player);

        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
        setVolumeControlStream(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
        PowerManager powerManager = (PowerManager) getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
        wakeLock = powerManager.newWakeLock(PowerManager.FULL_WAKE_LOCK, "Lexiconda");
        setUI();
        Intent mIntent = getIntent();
        songList=(ArrayList<GallryModel>) mIntent.getSerializableExtra("SongsList");
        currentTrack = mIntent.getIntExtra("position", 0);
        if(savedInstanceState ==null)
        {  

            mediaPlayer=((YeshuDuniaApplication) Songs_Player.this.getApplication()).medaiplayer;

            if(mediaPlayer.isPlaying())
            {   
                stop();

                playTrack(currentTrack);

            }
            else
            {

                playTrack(currentTrack);
                //Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Loaded " + Integer.toString(songList.size()) + " Tracks", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }


            //play(songList.get(currentTrack).getImage());
            btn_Play.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.pause);

        }



        btn_next.setOnClickListener(this); 
        btn_prev.setOnClickListener(this); 
        btn_Play.setOnClickListener(this); 


    }


    private void setUI()
    {
        //seek_bar = (SeekBar) findViewById(R.id.seek_bar);
        btn_next=(Button)findViewById(R.id.btn_mgallary_next);  
        btn_prev=(Button)findViewById(R.id.btn_mgallary_previous);      
        btn_Play=(Button)findViewById(R.id.btn_mgallary_Play);  
        bg = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.bg);
        txt_song_name=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.txt_song_name);

    }
    @Override
    public void onResume(){
        super.onResume();
        wakeLock.acquire();
    }
    //Play Songs.
    public void play(int currentTrack) throws MalformedURLException 
    {  this.currentTrack=currentTrack;
    System.out.println("Playiong track is"+currentTrack);
    this.song_url=songList.get(currentTrack).getSongUrl();
    if (!isPlaying) 
    {           
        isPlaying = true;
        btn_Play.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.pause);


        try {
            url = new URL(song_url);

            mediaPlayer.setLooping(false);

            mediaPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
            uri = Uri.parse(url.toURI().toString());

            mediaPlayer.setDataSource(uri.toString());
            //mediaPlayer.setOnPreparedListener(this);
            mediaPlayer.prepare();  
            mediaPlayer.start();




            mediaPlayer.setOnCompletionListener(this);
            // When song is ended then media player automatically called onCompletion method.

        }
        catch (MalformedURLException e) 
        {
            btn_Play.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.play);
            isPlaying=false;
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "File is not mp3 supported", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            e.printStackTrace();
        }   catch (IllegalArgumentException e) 
        {
            btn_Play.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.play);
            isPlaying=false;

            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "File is not mp3 supported", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (SecurityException e)
        {
            btn_Play.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.play);
            isPlaying=false;

            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "File is not mp3 supported", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IllegalStateException e)
        {
            btn_Play.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.play);
            isPlaying=false;

            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "File is not mp3 supported", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) 
        {
            btn_Play.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.play);
            isPlaying=false;

            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "File is not mp3 supported", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        catch (URISyntaxException e1) 
        {
            btn_Play.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.play);
            isPlaying=false;

            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "File is not mp3 supported", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    else
    {
        stop();

        play(currentTrack);
    }
    }

    //Stop song.
    public void stop()
    {
        synchronized(this)
        {
            isPlaying = false;
            if (mediaPlayer != null) 
            {
                mediaPlayer.reset();

            }
            //stopForeground(true);
        }
    }

    //Pause song.
    public void pause()
    {
        if (isPlaying) {
            isPlaying = false;
            if (mediaPlayer != null) 
            {
                mediaPlayer.pause();
                mediaPlayer = null;
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onPause()
    {
        super.onPause();
        wakeLock.release();

    }


    //Generate a String Array that represents all of the files found


    //Plays the Track
    public void playTrack(int currentTrack)
    {  
        this.currentTrack=currentTrack;
        //this.song_url=currentTrack;
        if(!isPlaying )
        {
            try {
                play(currentTrack);
                Toast.makeText(Songs_Player.this, "Playing " + songList.get(currentTrack).getSongTitle(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } catch (MalformedURLException e) 
            {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }

    }



    @Override
    public void onClick(View v)
    { boolean flag=false;
    switch(v.getId())
    {
    case R.id.btn_mgallary_Play:
        synchronized(this){
            if(isPlaying)
            {
                isPlaying = false;

                if (mediaPlayer != null) 
                { 
                    mediaPlayer.pause();
                }

                btn_Play.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.play);

            }
            else
            {
                isPlaying = true;
                mediaPlayer.start();
                btn_Play.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.pause);
                //playTrack(songList.get(currentTrack).getImage());
            }
        }
        return;
    case R.id.btn_mgallary_previous:

        stop();
        if(currentTrack == 0)
        {
            isPlaying=false;
            currentTrack=songList.size()-1;

            playTrack(currentTrack);

        }
        else
        {
            isPlaying=false;
            currentTrack=currentTrack-1;
            btn_Play.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.play);
            playTrack(currentTrack);


        }

        return;
    case R.id.btn_mgallary_next:
        stop();
        if(currentTrack == songList.size()-1)
        {
            isPlaying=false;
            currentTrack=0;
            btn_Play.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.play);
            playTrack(currentTrack);

        }
        else
        {
            isPlaying=false;
            btn_Play.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.play);
            currentTrack=currentTrack+1;
            playTrack(currentTrack);

        }

        return;
    default:
        return;
    }
    }
    @Override
    public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mediaPlayer) 
    {  
        mediaPlayer.stop();
        mediaPlayer.reset();
        if(currentTrack != songList.size()-1)
        {  isPlaying=false;
        currentTrack=currentTrack+1;
        btn_Play.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.play);
        playTrack(currentTrack);
        }
        else
        {  if(currentTrack == 0)
        {
            isPlaying=false;
            currentTrack=songList.size()-1;
            btn_Play.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.play);
            playTrack(currentTrack);
        }
        else
        {
            if(currentTrack == songList.size()-1)
            {
                isPlaying=false;
                currentTrack=0;
                btn_Play.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.play);
                playTrack(currentTrack);
            }
        }
        }

    }


}
```

It gove following error,

```
04-09 14:30:20.131: W/System.err(2414): java.net.URISyntaxException: Illegal character in path at index 58: http://www.yeshuduniya.com/admin/yeshuDuniyaMusic/25_Aamhi devachilekare/25_Aamhi devachilekare.mp3
04-09 14:30:20.131: W/System.err(2414):     at libcore.net.UriCodec.validate(UriCodec.java:63)
04-09 14:30:20.131: W/System.err(2414):     at java.net.URI.parseURI(URI.java:402)
04-09 14:30:20.131: W/System.err(2414):     at java.net.URI.<init>(URI.java:204)
04-09 14:30:20.131: W/System.err(2414):     at java.net.URL.toURI(URL.java:505)
04-09 14:30:20.131: W/System.err(2414):     at com.yeshuduniya.Songs_Player.play(Songs_Player.java:159)
04-09 14:30:20.131: W/System.err(2414):     at com.yeshuduniya.Songs_Player.playTrack(Songs_Player.java:275)
04-09 14:30:20.131: W/System.err(2414):     at com.yeshuduniya.Songs_Player.onCreate(Songs_Player.java:92)
04-09 14:30:20.131: W/System.err(2414):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231)
04-09 14:30:20.131: W/System.err(2414):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
04-09 14:30:20.131: W/System.err(2414):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2159)
04-09 14:30:20.131: W/System.err(2414):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2245)
04-09 14:30:20.131: W/System.err(2414):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
04-09 14:30:20.141: W/System.err(2414):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
04-09 14:30:20.141: W/System.err(2414):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
04-09 14:30:20.141: W/System.err(2414):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
04-09 14:30:20.141: W/System.err(2414):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
04-09 14:30:20.141: W/System.err(2414):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-09 14:30:20.141: W/System.err(2414):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
04-09 14:30:20.141: W/System.err(2414):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
04-09 14:30:20.141: W/System.err(2414):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
04-09 14:30:20.141: W/System.err(2414):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Please give me suggestion.

Comment: `25_Aamhi devachilekare`. the space is the problem

Answer (score 2):

Tru to use URLEncoder. For exmaple:

```
song_url = URLEncoder.encode(song_url);
```

Also you can provide `song_url` as datasource directly:

```
mediaPlayer.setDataSource(song_url);
mediaPlayer.prepare();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this..

You can use the `java.net.URLEncoder` to **encode** the **URL**

space need to replace with `%20` use below method to use your url **[URLEncoder](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/URLEncoder.html)**

**imports**

```
import android.webkit.URLUtil;
import android.util.Patterns;
import java.net.URLEncoder;
```

**Codes**

```
try {
     if(URLUtil.isValidUrl(song_url) || Patterns.WEB_URL.matcher(song_url).matches()) {
             song_url = URLEncoder.encode(song_url,"UTF-8");    
             url = new URL(song_url);   

            // so on                
     } else {
             Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Please enter valid URL.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
     }
    }
```